# Scheduling the next job in chain execution

Tags: c#, quartz.net

Goal is to make chain execution in Quartz. According to [documentation](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/faq.html) `JobKey()` method should be used for this. However the problem is that algorhitm is unable to schedule the next job.

Scheduler maintaner:

```
private static async Task Scheduler()
{
    try
    {
        NameValueCollection props = new NameValueCollection
        {
            { "quartz.serializer.type", "binary" }
        };
        StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);
        IScheduler scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();
        await scheduler.Start();
        await JobManagement(scheduler);
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45));
        await scheduler.Shutdown();
    }
    catch (SchedulerException se)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(se);
    }
}
```

JobManagement function:

```
private static async Task JobManagement(IScheduler scheduler)
{
    try
    {
        IJobDetail job1 = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
            .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
            .Build();

        IJobDetail job2 = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob2>()
            .WithIdentity("job2", "group2")
            .Build();

        IJobDetail jobWithException = JobBuilder.Create<JobWithException>()
            .WithIdentity("jobWithException", "jobsWithException")
            .Build();

        ITrigger triggerJob1 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("triggerJob1", "basic")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                .WithIntervalInSeconds(5)
                .RepeatForever())
            .Build();

        ITrigger triggerJob2 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("triggerJob2", "basic")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                .WithIntervalInSeconds(5)
                .RepeatForever())
            .Build();

        ITrigger triggerJobWithException = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("triggerJobWithException", "basic")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                .WithIntervalInSeconds(5)
                .RepeatForever())
            .Build();

        string chainGroup = "chainGroup";
        JobKey helloJobKey = JobKey.Create("jo1", chainGroup);
        JobKey hello2JobKey = JobKey.Create("job2", chainGroup);

        var listener = new JobChainingJobListener("listener");
        listener.AddJobChainLink(helloJobKey, hello2JobKey);

        scheduler.ListenerManager.AddJobListener(listener, GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupEquals("chainGroup"));

        await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job1, triggerJob1);
        await scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobWithException, triggerJobWithException);
    }
    catch (SchedulerException se)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(se);
    }
}
```

Instance of `job2` should be executed after the `job1` instnace is finished. At this point `job1` and `jobWithException` are the only ones executing.

Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by getting the corresponding JobKeys and add them to a chain (via listener).

```
string chainGroup = "chainGroup";
JobKey helloJobKey = JobKey.Create("HelloJob", chainGroup);
JobKey hello2JobKey = JobKey.Create("Hello2Job", chainGroup);

var listener = new JobChainingJobListener("listener");
listener.AddJobChainLink(helloJobKey, hello2JobKey);
```

Finally, you only have to define the listener to your scheduler.

```
scheduler.ListenerManager.AddJobListener(listener, GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupEquals("chainGroup"));
```

Comment: @Chyu call it before.